# User keeps deleting own question

Tags: support

Please see here: [Can I use a dictionary in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239611/thanks-for-answers)

What can/should be done?

**Add**

The same user also attempted the same with his other question: [More Efficient Way of List Function and Questioning/Answering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241181/more-efficient-way-of-list-function-and-questioning-answering)

Comment: After a sufficient number of rollbacks, a moderator flag is automatically raised. The most likely outcome is that a moderator restores the question and locks it to prevent further edits.

Comment: Did not know that, thanks for the info!

Comment: If they keep doing it, the post could be locked. There's already been a moderator involved on that page.

Comment: @Gabriel A moderator already commented on it. I suspect if the user keeps going he will be edit-banned or the post locked.

Comment: Moderator @matt has not locked the post in question

Comment: I was just about to remove the first line "I'm currently revising for my GCSE coursework" since the reason the user deleted it was: *deleted - dont want to share coursework thanks for answers*. Perhaps removing this line is a reasonable compromise? Any mods out there?

Comment: 'I'm currently revising for my GCSE coursework' - strange, but I can remember 'examinations' - I had to revise for those.  'Coursework', I had to do, well, actual work, by myself, without outsourcing it.

Comment: I would have put €100 on that question as likely to be deleted as soon as a suitable answer could be copyPasted out.  Can't have annoying profs detecting coursework cheats:(

Comment: LOL!!!  just seen that: ' dont want to share coursework thanks for answers' - as if OP had actually done all the work :)

Comment: @MartinJames It gets better: "this was deleted for a reason stop putting it back. I am allowed help but if someone else in my year finds this they could copy it and have a similar code which isnt allowed"

Comment: He was doing the same yesterday with his other question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35241181/revisions

Comment: Probably a moderator should check if they have any actual deleted questions as well that we can't see.

Comment: asker has just changed their name, they likely are afraid to be discovered