# Help out a woeful newbie with some constructive options

Tags: discussion, specific-question, new-users

I came across a single post that seemed strangely terse, especially since it got a few answers that went into details beyond what was in the question. A quick glance at [its latest edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34660609/revisions) indeed showed this was because of a rather drastic action from the OP: he deleted his problematic code and his question, leaving just an enigmatic statement which, on its own, would have begged for the usual "please include the code" and "what is your problem anyway".

Even more (as there is no rest for the wickedly paranoid), when I decided to check out his other questions, he did the same to [his 3 other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5744337/turtle-23?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Yet, still not satisfied, he attempted to push edits through on [two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5744337/turtle-23?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

So I left him a [comment on one of his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660609/csv-to-text-file-layout#comment58521999_34660609), rolled back the lot, and rejected the edits (much to my fortune, there were no robo-reviewers on line today).

**Mission Accomplished.**

... Some time later, it got me thinking.

Why would anyone do this? Well, obviously this was part of some homework, and – per the attempted answer-editing – the OP was not smart enough to use dummy function names.

So we are now actively punishing him *because* we are doing the Right Thing (According To Stack Overflow). And we're not doing his classmates a favor either, when they find out a casual Google search will yield on-topic advice, given by some of the best Python programmers around. (I'm guessing this last part.) In addition, he probably cannot use his current SO account anymore.

However, all is not lost. I think we can best help him, his classmates, and anyone else with similar questions on Python by:

1. *Not* deleting these questions.
2. *Disassociating* the questions from his account (this needs his approval).
3. *Anonymizing* the code in the questions.

"We", the community, are responsible to act upon inappropriate use of Stack Overflow content – as proven by the quick restoration of the defaced questions. However, that does **not** mean we 'therefore' are *not* responsible for any ensuing damage for an individual.

I feel we should go try and fix this.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this differs from the current policy for homework questions.

Comment: *So we are now actively punishing him.* It may sound harsh, but I personally do not care the slightest about this. Users that dump their homework here, then realize it basically gives them away and want to cover their traces are a plague on this site -- let them deal with the consequences of their actions.

Comment: related: [User keeps deleting own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316368/839601)

Comment: How?  Reprogram the OP's brain so that s/he does not abuse SO anymore?

Comment: Posting a homework question comes with it's own risks...we're not responsible for mitigating those risks.

Comment: Anonymizing code is not a big deal if done properly. I personally would not object to other users anonymising code in my answers if they don't mess it up. That said, it is _absolutely not_ our responsibility to do this. Do so if you must, but thats you.

Comment: 'S/he probably cannot use his current SO account anymore' well, with 11 rep, 'Member for 43 days', 'This user has not answered any questions', not exactly a huge loss.

Comment: @Magisch: it's neither my *responsibility* to maintain a good quality on SO, nor is restoring damaged questions – as I did now. As the entire thing made me feel quite bad, I don't think I will ever do so again.

Comment: @Jongware In fact, moderators have sometimes been known to mail professors about blatantly cheating students.

Comment: Users that dump their own homework here is bad enough . There are those who dump other students' homework here, take the answers from the rep-PersonalServicesWorkers and sell the answers back to the students.  I no longer give a toss about whatever trouble students might get into by posting on SO.

Comment: If you wake up in a particularly good mood one day, and decide to drop a hint, you get punished for your good deed; 'Your var 'count' is uninitialized, set it to 1'......'Plz, dont understand post complete code'.  Sod 'em:(

Comment: Even if you get code, it will probably be a misrepresentation.  Code copied in an uncompleted form from another student, code copied from the net, code that has some 'runtime error' when it blatantly could not ever compile, (because instead of copypasta from a development source file, they have typed it in from paper-typed homework).  I've had enough of them.

Comment: @MartinJames you remember the one I fell for with the pseudocode?

Comment: ^^ lol, yes, just about.  A lot of sewage has flowed under the troll-bridge since then:)

Answer (score 18):

It is not the responsibility of the community to anonymize code to protect the asker. The asker had all the time in the world to revise their code and create a minimal example *before* they posted their question. Once something is posted publicly, the cat's out of the bag.

Historically, there are a couple of situations where we see people trying to redact their questions in this manner: a student wants to hide any traces of cheating on assignments or tests (either realizing after the fact that their professor can use Google, or planning from the beginning to delete their question as soon as they got their answer), or a contractor / employee posts proprietary code.

Generally, I will roll back any such redactions that I see and warn users about this. If they start arguing that this is necessary or they will be fired / expelled, I will typically suggest that they find a way to anonymize the code themselves or offer to dissociate the question from their account. If people have taken the time to provide good answers to their questions, I'm not about to let them disrespect these people by taking their ball and going home.

The burden is on them to figure out what's best in this situation, not on us to determine how we as a community could anonymize this code. We might not even know what parts are or are not proprietary in this.

For the rarer cases where personally identifying information has been disclosed, we will step in and remove that, particularly if it endangers innocent third parties. (The number of HIPAA violations I've had to report to various agencies in my time as a moderator saddens me.)

Comment: Wow, HIPAA violations. I never would have guessed. Clearly our medical data is in good hands with the world's elite programmers!

Comment: When I see such behavior, I flag it as vandalism. Users are not allowed to vandalize any posts, including their own.

Comment: @CodyGray - What I've seen has opened my eyes to how the security of all of our medical and personal information is dependent on the worst contractor this work has been outsourced to.

Comment: @JDB you don't attempt to rollback first? I'd think the procedure would be to rollback, and only flag as vandalism on repeated offense. It -is- something that "the community" has the tools to resolve themselves first before it is escalated to the poor overworked slav... mods.

Comment: @Gimby - Yes, you are correct. I'd rollback first, then report vandalism if the user attempts it a second time. In this case of mass vandalism (as reported here) I'd probably report vandalism anyway, just to give the mods an opportunity to address the user about this behavior (as the likelihood of repeat offenses is, in my opinion, significantly higher).

Comment: Latin quotes auto-generate -100 rep.

Answer (score 10):

We are not responsible for hiding the fact that the OP is cheating on his homework.

We are also not punishing him at all, for anything.  He might end up getting punished by his school if he is caught cheating.  If he is punished as a result of *being the one who choose to cheat* then that's a consequence that he accepted when he made the decision in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Homeworks are supposed to **force** you to learn for that **specific** topic. If you cannot manage solving that problem on your own, well, you can ask on SO for **advices** or for **hints**, not for the full solution. Not only does that mean to cheat on your teacher, but it also **completely defies** the purpose of homework.

Many people here on SO still answer on these questions despite better knowledge (they do it for the rep I suppose), but that's it. If you are not smart enough to expect your teacher to google your results... Well, that's your **own fault** then.

I also would not say we're "punishing" them, we are just not supporting their actions & behaviour. If they fail their class due to that I surely won't shed a tear.

Comment: *"well, you can ask on SO for advices or for hints,"* Really? I'd find it an achievement if you manage to ask for advice or hints in a way that makes a valid non-duplicate SO question.

Comment: @Gimby SO has a chat. Most people there are very nice if you ask for advice/hints/clues without asking for a full solution.

Comment: @Gimby Most chat users will play ball provided the students are a) not obnoxious b) not blatantly spamming their problem and c) not completly lacking understanding.

Comment: @Magisch OK but, umm... how many does that leave, on an average day?  Is it a round number?

Comment: @MartinJames Somewhere in the 1/10000 range

Comment: @seth (and Magisch) right, I never remember that chat is a thing :) Still, chat isn't really the same as asking "on SO" to me. Perhaps specifically name it in the answer.