# Can askers delete their questions that have answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Something strange just happened to me: I had just written an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481159/mysql-select-query-get-record-if-is-default-1-otherwise-is-default-0), which I can no longer see, and after posting it, while I was editing it, I got a message saying that the post was no longer available.

Is this standard behaviour or was it some kind of bug? I thought questions with answers could not be deleted.

Comment: It needs multiple answers or 1 answer with a positive score to protect the question from deletion

Comment: see also: [User keeps deleting own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316368/user-keeps-deleting-own-question)

Comment: The answer is of really low quality (code only without any explanation why it is working compared to OP's code), so I'd not worry too much about it :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Questions are protected from deletion by the author in 3 cases:

1. The question has multiple answers.
2. The question has a single answer with an upvote.
3. The question has an accepted answer (which is not really a serious deterrent since the OP can unaccept an answer before deleting, but is included here for completeness sake)

In your case, the OP appears to have deleted the question before your post was able to get upvoted and before anyone was able to leave a second answer.

In some cases, it could be an innocent coincidence, in that the OP decided to delete right before you left your answer and you managed to sneak your answer in first.  But it is just as common (or perhaps more so) that the author waited for an answer and immediately deleted the question (usually happens with homework so the OP doesn't get caught for cheating).

You may also be interested to know that this type of deletion could be considered a hostile act by the system, and users who continually do this are very likely to earn themselves a [question-ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: @MatteoTassinari In another 412 rep, you'll be able to cast a manual delete vote on it, anyway.

Comment: Actually I had a answer that was upvoted (from last year around the time I joined), and someone then downvoted it, obviously to remove the "1 positive vote" criteria, and then it got deleted 4 hours later. I found it odd, because why downvote, and then delete? Now I know why. Happened just last week. So I don't think upvotes are much of a help, since you can always get enough downvotes to counter a question you want gone.

Comment: Are deleted answers taken into account?

Comment: @Oriol No, deleted answers are not considered for this.

Comment: "The question has a single answer with an upvote" should probably be "...with positive score" since downvotes are also taken into account.

Comment: @Pshemo there was some debate about that initially (looks like the comments were deleted, but you can see that in the original version of this answer), so we followed the [MSE details on deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Then maybe it is worth to compromise both like "...with an up-vote (or to be more precise with positive score since down-votes also matters)". Anyway thanks for information that this was already discussed.

Comment: I had a highly upvoted, and sole answer deleted.  Granted it could be considered inflammatory to some working at microsoft, but it was a valid response to the question/issue at hand.   I can't even search for my answer anymore, but it was regarding signed assemblies showing as untrustworthy on windows.

Comment: @JasonS we are talking about deletion by the asker. 10kers can vote to delete a Q&A without regards of the upvotes.

Comment: @Pshemon the problem is that exact statement may not be accurate.  Based on the feedback in those deleted comments and [the answer linked to the answered I linked above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471), a positive score is not necessary.