# Can questions be marked as private by the "asker" after they are answered?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to hide/mark-as-private your questions after they have been marked as answered? Such that they can't be found by a google search or so? The only solution I see is to delete them altogether. Is there an alternative? (If not, why not? Think it would be a handy feature.)

Yes, my concerns are homework related, however my questions are researched, and I come on here to ask a question as a last resort. I don't ask for just a solution, I am genuinely trying to understand and improve my coding. If they were just to beg for code, they would be down-voted anyway. I don't understand why this is "cheating"? How am I to learn if it is against the rule to ask questions?

Comment: Is this so you can't be caught cheating on your homework? I can't think of much other point.

Comment: You won't even be able to delete them if there's an answer with at least one upvote.

Comment: No. Such a feature is completely counter to [the point of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): 

*With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.*

Comment: Picture this: *all* Stack Overflow questions that have been helpful for you were "private". Do you like that?

Comment: @Anon001, since you haven't explained why would it be useful to "hide" your post, people are assuming your question is homework related, and you don't want to be caught asking for help in something that maybe you are meant to research by yourself.

Comment: It is actually of no concern to us if you are cheating or not. The important bit is that if posters hide their questions (after they have been answered), SO loses its value.

Comment: @vaultah yup... and then the question is going to be *asked again* and no-one will know it's a dupe because perfectly good QA pairs will be hidden - so  that means someone's had to spend time *asking* and then other people will spend time *answering* it again... It'd be a complete mess and waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @Anon001 If you're not cheating, there is no reason to hide your questions afterwards. If you don't want to get caught asking those questions, you're almost certainly cheating.

Comment: Also, note that by the time a question is marked as answered, it had been copied by dozens of scrapers, many of which are indexed by Google. Hiding a question on Stack Overflow will not remove it from elsewhere.

Comment: @MadScientist I don't want to be accused of cheating if I have gone to a 3rd party to ask for help.

Comment: @Anon001, again; the important part is not about cheating. That's a red-herring for this question. You can cheat if you want. But (generally speaking) you can't delete or hide content you post to SO; because it goes counter to the rules and goals of the site. **The cheating part people are picking on, IMO is actually not relevant to this question**.

Comment: We're not the ones who decide what is considered cheating and what is not - that's the job of your examination board/instructor. The only thing we care about is the content - and if it's of any value it should not be deleted nor hidden.

Comment: _"Think it would be a handy feature."_ Why? You have no justification for your proposal; [edit] and explain why you think this would be "handy".

Comment: If you're looking for 1-on-1 closed-room tutoring then this is indeed not the community you'll want. That doesn't make it *"elitist"* and there's no real need to get offensive just because we're not about to change the entire site to fit your needs.

Comment: You asked if questions can be marked private and got "no" as an answer. That you don't like this answer is no reason to call the community elitist.

Comment: Apart from the goal of SO (create a repository of q and a for all users) consider the following scenario: you ask a question and get a wrong answer, or one that isn't using best practices. By hiding it it cannot be voted upon, and you won't get to see different approaches for solving the problem. You could get a mediocre or wrong answer without ever noticing it.

Comment: @ModusTollens I think they're still hung up on the cheating accusation.

Comment: What I find confusing is that, up until you edited in that the community was elitist, your questions had actually been well received. Other than some noise your questions looked OK: explained the specific issue you were having and included code. You were getting answers and up votes. I don't understand why you'd even want this feature.

Comment: see also: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/839601)

Answer (score 76):

No, there is no such feature.

No, such a feature would not be desirable.

Stack Overflow is not your personal help desk. We are not here to help *just you* with a problem. The reason we volunteer our time for free to help you is because our answers to you will also help *many other* people in the future. If there was a way for you to make your question "private" after it was answered, than that would subvert the entire goal of this site.

And before you get any ideas about *deleting* your questions after they have been answered as a "workaround", note that this is considered abusive behavior and is not allowed. In fact, [the system will prevent you from doing so in certain cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317138/can-askers-delete-their-questions-that-have-answers). If you make a habit of doing this, you will find yourself blocked from asking any more questions.