# Rollback of an OP edit was rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I am looking for feedback about the reject of [my suggested rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18647336).

---

It looks like the OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113124/int-is-not-iterable-error-sudoku-printing-error) wants, in some kind, destroy/hide his question.

At first he edited his question and removed the desired output and changed some simple numbers.

I know, we should

> ► always respect the original author

but in my eyes the edit does not make any sense.

After the edit of his question, he unaccepted my answer and wants [to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18581660) my answer (which he had accepted previously) in a destructive way.

Later on I just [suggested a rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18647336) to restore the desired output but this was rejected as

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

---

So was my rollback really inappropriated?

Comment: The reviewers acted rashly, IMO. Your edit comment, brief as it was,  described the situation. (It could have been slightly longer. E.g. _"rollback to restore desired output, **since the question already has answers dealing with the aforementioned output**"_). Maybe they could have checked the edit history before clicking _reject_. Or if it was too much work, just skip it and let the robo-reviewers approve your suggested edit in the course of their work-day...

Comment: @yivi The comment just says *that* it's a rollback, not why the rollback is merited.  Even looking at it now, I don't see why the question is better with that information than it is without it.  It seems irrelevant to the problem at hand, and the answer as a result, thus removing it seems *appropriate*.  Now I don't know if the reviewers thought that through or came to the same conclusion for a bad reason, but at the very least I expect the revision note to explain *why* the rollback is beneficial to the question.

Comment: @Servy, yes you are right. Still, if I saw a suggested edit and the edit message mentioned something along the lines of "rollback to restore blah, blah", I would visit the question before making up my mind. Seeing that the user that suggested the rollback is the same than the one answering the question would have been valuable information, so the question timeline. Not staying that the edit message couldn't have used more love though.

Comment: @Servy|yivi: The empty text in the edit summary says: _briefly explain your changes_. So I thought __Rollback to restore desired output__ is enough to explain why I want the rollback. I would agree with you that the desired output is not essential, but in my eyes it make the question a little bit better. But I don't want to start a discussion about that :)

Comment: @yivi And I'm saying that, having looked at the question, I see no reason why this rollback is merited.  Sure, if the OP had done some obvious vandalism, to the extent that no one could look at it and think that a rollback wasn't needed, then you can risk not providing a reason, but looking quite closely at this post I see no reason why the edit should be rolled back.  It seems fine.  And given that no reason was given for the rollback, and none is apparent, declining it is appropriate.

Comment: I never read the question answer. I assumed that the desired output _was_ essential to your answer. If it wasn't... there wasn't any reason to edit it back.

Comment: @Servy, I agree, **I hadn't** looked closely at either question or answer.

Comment: @MartinBackasch That's just saying *what* you did, not why you did it.  Reading it we can see *that* you were rolling back an edit, not why rolling back the edit makes the question better.  Given that you feel the information isn't important to the question, the question is *better* without it than with it, so rejecting it is entirely appropriate.  Adding back in relevant information that was correctly removed is making the question *worse*, not better.

Comment: @Servy The OP wrote  _"I can't seem to get the "|" to print. instead of "in" in the if statement I tried "==" but this gave me the output minus the "|". Where as I going wrong?"_ so in some kind it is relevant to the question to visualize what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @MartinBackasch The problem, as the question describes , is that it just doesn't compile.  That's the question that is being asked about, and that it is looking for an answer for.  Once they're able to iterate over the values they want their question is answered.  What their program is doing once it's able to iterate over the values it needs is outside of the scope of the question.  The OP included it for extra context, but apparently removed it because they felt it was distracting from their actual problem.  You focusing on it, rather than their actual problem, is just proving that point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rollback was not appropriate as edit did not in any way changed meaning of the question or made it objectively worse by SO standards.

Suggested edit of your answer on other hand is very suspicious. I would consider to flag post for moderator attention and explain your concerns ("suggested edit {link} is vandalism and seem to try to hide homework answer, see edit of the Q at the same time."). Moderator may also consider rollback of question edit and lock the question (also letting system to simply block the OP is another option - some discussion [Can questions be marked as private by the "asker" after they are answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355415/can-questions-be-marked-as-private-by-the-asker-after-they-are-answered)).

Answer (score -8):

The OP isn't trying to destroy their question at all.  They are removing some irrelevant information from their question that was distracting readers from what they were really asking about.  You were trying to edit that irrelevant information back in.  That edit was *correctly* rejected.

Comment: Taking up your last comment from above and also following your thoughts about _removing some irrelevant information_.  Did this also mean, I should remove the last part of my answer and only leave the parts where I answered why it does not compile and how to fix it. Or is it okay to let it there.

Comment: @MartinBackasch That's your decision to make.  You're certainly *allowed* to include additional information in your answer, beyond what it takes to answer the question, if you think it's helpful.  You're also free to remove it if you don't think that it's helpful.

Comment: Sadly, the backlash You got here Servy only shows that most of "the community" is not responsible enough to give them **any kind of edit 
 privileges**.  Therefore, at least 50% of current privilege thresholds are much, much lower than they should be.
It's always been and issue, I don't understand why everyone are dodging this. As always, _the truth hurts, doesn't it_??